# Condição if script não reconhece valor retornado

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá, eu tenho seguinte código:

```
function addUser(value){

var adduser = value;
var useremail = localStorage.getItem('email');
var userpassword = localStorage.getItem('password');
var acao = "adicionar";


$.post('http://localhost/app/searchplayer.php', {useremail : useremail, userpassword : userpassword, acao : acao, adduser : adduser}, function(retorna){

    if(retorna == "sucesso2"){

    alert (retorna);

    }

}); 

}
```

e o código php eu tenho um único echo que retorna sucesso2  (echo "sucesso2";)  porém na condição if do script ele não retorna o alert. Se eu apenas colocar alert(retorna); ele retorna o alerta com o valor sucesso2 porém com a condição if ele não retorna. Alguma idéia do que pode ser?

Comment: Desculpe, mas qual o valor de retorna? Que tal colocar um "}else{alert('qual o valor de retorna?')}; Vê o que acontece?

Comment: Talvez seja um espaço que tenha e não veja. tente `if(retorna.trim() == "sucesso2") {....`

Comment: @MagicHat - Ele retorna o valor de echo em uma página php, que no caso é o sucesso2.

Comment: @Miguel testei com o <code>if(retorna.trim() == "sucesso2") {....<code> e funcionou. Agora a questão de ser um espaço, aparentemente não existe nenhum. O que seria a função .trim()? obrigado

Comment: A função trim, presente em diversas linguagens remove espaços presentes nas extremidades e usa string, seja espaçamentos no inicio ou no fim da string.

Answer (score 0):

A função de sucesso do `$.post` tem que ser declarada dentro do mesmo objeto onde vão as configurações da requisição, na propriedade `success`. Também tem outro erro: você declarou todos os dados de postagem no mesmo objeto. Tudo o que você declarou para o `POST` vai dentro de um objeto `data` que fica dentro do mesmo objeto onde estão as configurações da requisição. O código da solução está abaixo:

```
/**
 * Adiciona um usuário.
 * @param number value
 */
function addUser(value){
    // Organização de dados
    var user = {
        add: value,
        email: localStorage.getItem('email'),
        password: localStorage.getItem('password'),
        action: "adicionar"
    };

    // Envia uma requisição para o servidor.
    $.post("http://localhost/app/searchplayer.php",
    {
        // Dados que vão para a requisição.
        data: {
            useremail : user.email,
            userpassword : user.password,
            acao : user.action,
            adduser : user.add
        },

        // Callback de sucesso
        success: function(response) {
            if(response === "sucesso2") {
                alert(response);
            }
        }
    });
}
```